# Software advice - for creating animations

Tags: video, windows, software-recommendation

I need to make a sort of animation. Not that I am going for same feel or style but I would like to make something that is sort of similar to the animated sequences in "*Monty Pyhton's Flying Circus*".

There is one catch though! **I need to attach some collage/clip-art to something that can easily be distorted into a 3D-perspective** - so I can move 'a virtual camera' around imported 2D-images(bitmap) in 3D-space (hope that's clear enough). Currently I am passing on Flash, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a starter go for after effects, check [videocopilot.net](http://www.videocopilot.net) for subject of interest..

short:

new project, import your prerpared files, create new camera, drag your footage to the timeline, mark the 3d layer switch, set up the positions of the layers(x y z) and roll the camera ;)